# Trying to find java petstore 2.0

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have searched for java petstore 2.0 with no luck. The link http://java.net/projects/blueprints/downloads.html says "not found". I am trying to get a grip on j2ee and would like to go through a sample project.

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://java.net/projects/petstore ? Also, some dev.java projects are moved to kenai.com, FYI

Answer (score 5):

Valid link for PetStore sources http://java.net/projects/petstore