# The Java Petstore 2.0 Blueprint

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, sun, blueprint

I am currently trying to find the jave ee 5 blueprint of the pet store 2.0. The pages which have been linked by sun aren't valid anymore. I also tried to find the pages at oracle.

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/code/

Does anyone know where i can find the blueprint?

THX

Comment: You can refer a similar post @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604070/trying-to-find-java-petstore-2-0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I also tried to find the pages at
>   oracle."

I'm afraid you need to work on your Google-Fu because all the Java blueprints are listed on the Oracle website.  [Find them here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/blueprints-141945.html)

Comment: I was seeking for an online version of the blueprint. But with the repository i can access the blueprints with a local. That's okay.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in the SVN repository via http://java.net/projects/petstore

Comment: @ich-bin-drin: Don't expect too much!